# Combine functionality of @ModelAttribute and @RequestBody in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Consider a **@PostMapping** in Spring MVC, and we want to map the request body to a DTO, as well as other request parameters like query and path variables.

For **mapping the request body** we can use the **@RequestBody** annotation on a parameter, which will tell Spring to use the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

For **mapping the request parameters** we can use the **@ModelAttribute** annotation (or avoid any annotations; same effect), which will tell Spring to use the `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`.

But is there an easy way to **combine these two**? Is there a way to make spring first map the DTO with request parameters and then override with data deserialized from the JSON in the body?

The only way I see it at the moment is to create a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but I'd like to reuse any existing Spring functionality first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out no, not at time of writing anyway.

`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getDefaultArgumentResolvers` holds the    default configuration for the argument resovlers, and we have:

- `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` handling the `@RequestBody` annotation, and
- `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor` handling the `@ModelAttribute`, or any parameter without any annotations.

It's always just one single resolver that gets executed, even if you try using a composite.

### My solution

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ServletRequestBinderRequestBodyAdvice extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

    private final ServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        copyDefaultPropertiesThatWhereOverwritenWithNull(parameter, body);

        new ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder(body).bind(servletRequest);

        return body;
    }

    private void copyDefaultPropertiesThatWhereOverwritenWithNull(MethodParameter parameter, Object arg) {
        Object argWithDefaults = instantiateClass(parameter.getParameterType());
        copyPropertiesSkippingNulls(argWithDefaults, arg);
    }

}
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but if it helps someone, I am able to combine the both and it works successfully `processSuccess(Model model, @ModelAttribute("success") @RequestBody SuccessDto successDto`